# How to update UITableView with managed Objects?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data

on viewDidLoad i init my array:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Member" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[sortDescriptors release];
[sortDescriptor release];
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
[self setMemberArray:mutableFetchResults];
[mutableFetchResults release];
[request release];
```

this all works like it should, in the TableView i work with the MemberArray, but how and where do i update my array if something changed?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `NSFetchedResultsController` instead of managing the array yourself.  Then you would only need to react to the `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods instead of trying to determine when something has changed.